# Replacing If/Else Statements Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a tic tac toe game user enter input one line string of all columns and rows of Xs and Os like this 'O_OOXOOXX' i turn them into nested list like this [['O', '_', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'X']]

My question is how can replace all the if elif below? because it seems a lot.

```
for i in range(3):
   if nested_list[i][0] == nested_list[i][1] == nested_list[i][2] == 'O':
      print('O wins')
   elif nested_list[0][i] == nested_list[1][i] == nested_list[2][i] == 'O':
      print('O wins')
   elif nested_list[0][0] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[2][2] == 'O':
      print('O wins')
   elif nested_list[0][2] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[2][0] == 'O':
      print('O wins')

   elif nested_list[i][0] == nested_list[i][1] == nested_list[i][2] == 'X':
      print('X wins')
   elif nested_list[0][i] == nested_list[1][i] == nested_list[2][i] == 'X':
      print('X wins')
   elif nested_list[0][0] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[2][2] == 'X':
      print('X wins')
   elif nested_list[0][2] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[2][0] == 'X':
      print('X wins')
```

Comment: You could use `or` between conditions that have the same effect.

Comment: You can make a list containing all the conditions which leads to win and check if the condition exists in current game

Comment: You have to come up with a different algorithm, it's not a specific quiestion, "how to make less ifs"

Comment: If your game works and you just need some help in improving the code, you could post it to [Code review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I thought about it but the code still gonna be long, is there a loop i can use to replace the index like i did with 'i'

Comment: Look at the patterns between all these different checks, and how each one is different, and how each one is the same. How do they ***vary***? What are the ***variables*** in each case? Can you express those ***variables*** in an automated fashion?

Comment: At least you can do this with 4 ifs instead of 8. As you can see, patterns for X and O are same

Comment: @user2314737, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured another solution:

```
arr = ['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X']
```

I determine a nested list of possible wins

```
matches = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5],
           [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6],
           [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
           [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

for i in range(8):
if(arr[matches[i][0]] == 'X' and
   arr[matches[i][1]] == 'X' and
   arr[matches[i][2]] == 'X'):
     print(X wins)
else:
  print(O wins)
```

and now i'm trying to figure out the other possibilities
for example
if the game not finished
if the there is 3 Xs and Os in row then the game is impossible...

Answer (score 1):

Probabily there's a nicer solution, but maybe something like this?

```
for i in range(3):
    a = set(nested_list[i,:])
    b = set(nested_list[:,i])
    if(len(a) == 1 && nested_list[i,0] != '_')
        print(nested_list[i,0], " wins")
    elif(len(b) == 1 && nested_list[0,i] != '_')
        print(nested_list[0,i], " wins")
if (((nested_list[0][0] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[2][2]) || nested_list[2][0] == nested_list[1][1] == nested_list[0][2])) && nested_list[1][1] != '_'):
    print(nested_list[1][1], " wins")
```

Comment: `a[0]` does not work when `a` is a set.

Comment: @kaya3 You're right, my bad. Fixed it